# Problem in boot up(14.04); asking passphrase

Tags: 14.04, passphrase

A very basic question I'm afraid, but I did not do the installation of 14.04, and when I boot up I am asked for a passphrase (sda5_crypt), does this mean my disk is encrypted, and if so what are the consequences for recovering data in the event of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installation wizard offers to setup a disk encryption (besides the protection of you user and admin/root accounts). It might be even activated by default (so that it would have have been necessary to deactivated it explicitly in order to avoid it at installation). During the installation you have been certainly asked to enter a password besides your user password.

Maybe you entered your user password?

Comment: Thank you, but as I said I did not set up my system, so I amk unaware of what was entered. Also I cannot reach the person who did the setup however I appreciate your comments.

Comment: Did you get any other password from the person who installed Ubuntu for you (you also need a password to log into you user account). Try all of them. If you are sure that you don't have any personal data on the partition where Ubuntu has been installed (and that the person who installed Ubuntu didn't put any personal data there), I guess the easiest way is to overwrite the encrypted installation with a new Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Thank you, I need a log in password, but also have a different password when installing programmes and such like. My question is basically this :"because I am asked for a "passphrase" on log in, and then am told 'successful log in' and then passed on to normal log in" is my disk encrypted?" if so I have read there may be difficulties with data recovery in the future. I'd appreciate some further comments as I cannot find answers in the documentation. Thank you again for your trouble in replying.

Comment: So you're not having "trouble in boot up" which works fine according to your last comment (?), but a question on system setup implications? You should edit the question, especially the title, and add your reference to what you have read about possible problem and post your logs.

Comment: Thank you once again, I apologise for the wording, it was a "problem" with my understanding. Upon further reading it appears the disk was encrypted on installation and I'm now happy to leave it that way. I feel I have gleaned all I can from the forum in regard to this query. Thank you all.